# How to calculate V in the following questions? What does the two arrows mean?

Tags: electricity

[image] What does the two arrows means in the following questions?

Comment: How did your professor explain them? This looks like a multiple choice homework or quiz question.

Comment: I found those questions while using Microelectronic circuits : Theory & Applications 7th edition as I'm preparing for a test and couldn't answer those questions

Comment: I can see three arrows in each example above where you wrote your question. Can you be clearer about the two you mention?

Comment: Actually, I can see four if you count the diode symbols as arrows.

Comment: the 2 at the terminals

Answer (score 1):

The two arrows simply indicate a power supply connection, in your case positive 3V and negative 3V, so you have a total of 6V applied across the resistor-diode combination.
The single arrow with "I" next to it indicates the direction of the current flow. It's giving you a hint whether the diode is forward or reverse biased (I hope you have read the text before these examples, because then you will understand the meaning of forward and reverse bias).
These circuits simply show how to "clamp" a voltage with a diode.
You don't even have to calculate the voltage (or, more precisely, POTENTIAL) indicated at the output as "V" if you know how a diode behaves.
A diode will have about 0.6V across it when forward biased (its cathode towards negative voltage), and it will have a full voltage across it if reverse biased.
The first example will give you (-3V)+(0.6V)=-2.4V

EDIT: I have looked at the book, and it talks about "ideal diodes" (zero volts forward drop), so that makes it even easier to figure out (don't even need to calculate):
The first example will give you -3V.
I will let **you** figure out the other voltages. All it requires is a little bit of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow next to the “I” is indicating the direction of the current running through the diode.